# how to display data on click react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Implemented writing data from the form to the array. Everything works. but now I want to implement data output when I click on " SEND ARR "
When I hang up a click on a button, respectively, the data is not displayed since in the function we access event.target.value

Please tell me how to rewrite the line so that I can display data when I click on the button? thank

home.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./../App.css"


export default class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()


        this.state = {
            count: 1,
            objexm: '',
            inputValue: '',
            arr: []
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.updateInputValue = this.updateInputValue.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1
        });
    };


    createMarkup() {
        return {
            __html: this.state.inputValue
        };
    };

    updateInputValue(event) {
        let newArr = this.state.arr;
        let newlist = event.target.value;
        if (event.target.value) {
            newArr.push(newlist)
        }
        this.setState({
            inputValue: newArr
        });
        event.target.value = '';
    };


    render() {
        return (

            <div className="home-header">
                <h2>{this.state.count}</h2>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Add</button>

                <input type='text' name="names" onClick={this.updateInputValue} />

                {this.state.arr.map((arrs, index) => {
                    return (
                        <li
                            key={index}
                        >{arrs}</li>
                    )
                })}

<button>SEND ARR</button>
                <ul className="qwe">
                    <li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup()}></li>
                </ul>
            </div>


        );
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you want to output your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the data from the input into **invputValue** each time the input is updated and on the click of the button update the **arr** content with the old values (***...arr***) plus the current input value (***this.state.inputValue***) .
To make sure the old values are not deleted the **arr** is defined at the top of the class ***let arr = []***. If you don't want it there you can instantiate it in the constructer which will run only once. i.e. ***this.arr = []***

```js
let arr = []
class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            count: 1,
            objexm: '',
            inputValue: '',
            arr: []
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.updateInputValue = this.updateInputValue.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1
        });
    };

    createMarkup() {
        return {
            __html: this.state.inputValue
        };
    };

    updateInputValue = e => {
      this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value })
    }

    displayData = () => {
      arr = [...arr ,this.state.inputValue]
      this.setState({ arr, inputValue: "" })
    }

    clearData = () => {
      this.setState({ arr: [] })
    }

    render() {
      console.log("this.state.arr:", this.state.arr)
        return (

            <div className="home-header">
                <h2>{this.state.count}</h2>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Add</button>

                <input type='text' name="names" onChange={this.updateInputValue} value={this.state.inputValue} />

                {this.state.arr.map((arrs, index) => {
                    return (
                        <li
                            key={index}
                        >{arrs}</li>
                    )
                })}

                <button onClick={this.displayData}>SEND ARR</button>
                <button onClick={this.clearData}>CLEAR ARR</button>
                <ul className="qwe">
                    <li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup()}></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thank! And yet, how to clear the form after clicking on the button?

Comment: Do you mean the list? If you want to clear just make another button and  in that button reset arr [this.setState({arr:  []})]

Comment: meant to clear the "input field" itself after sending,.,after a click, the values ​​in the input field remain and are not erased

Comment: I update the code with the changes you want. If you're satisfied you can vote me up.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to respond. I understand correctly that: this.setState ({arr, inputValue: ""})
replaces "arr" with "arr from state" and adds an empty "inputValue"?

Comment: Well arr is not from state. it's the array on top of the class(previous array) plus the current inputValue from state. Yes set inputValue to "" afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `onClick` on input, use `onChange` and update value in state i.e. make the input a controlled component . Post that onClick of button take the value from state and push to the array and clear the input value

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()


        this.state = {
            count: 1,
            objexm: '',
            inputValue: '',
            arr: []
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.updateInputValue = this.updateInputValue.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            count: prevState.count + 1,
            inputValue: [...prevState.inputValue, prevState.name],
            name: ""
        }));
    };


    createMarkup() {
        return {
            __html: this.state.inputValue
        };
    };

    updateInputValue(event) {
        let newVal = event.target.value;
        this.setState({
            name: newVal
        });
    };


    render() {
        return (

            <div className="home-header">
                <h2>{this.state.count}</h2>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Add</button>

                <input type='text' name="names" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.updateInputValue} />

                {this.state.arr.map((arrs, index) => {
                    return (
                        <li
                            key={index}
                        >{arrs}</li>
                    )
                })}

<button>SEND ARR</button>
                <ul className="qwe">
                    <li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup()}></li>
                </ul>
            </div>


        );
    }
}
```